# Network speed slow on CAT5e cables

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I have a cable running through my walls directly connected to my modem, and going to a wall socket. When i run a speedtest on my computer by directly connecting to the wall socket, i get around 90 Mbit/s. However, if i run a cable directly from my modem to my computer, i get 270 Mbit/s.

This must mean there is a problem with the cable going through the wall. When I inspect the cable i see that it's CAT5e, and the wires seem to be connected correctly (from what i googled) Here are some pictures of the connections:

[image: connections]

What might be the problem?
I hope it has something to do with the connections as I don't think its even possible to replace the cable since it doesnt budge when i pull it on either side.

Comment: Its possible the cable behind the wall socket has a breach and is now prone to interference, or the wiring on the other end of the cable from the wall socket is incorrect, unless that's the modem part of the plug.

Comment: is there *any* other equipment between the modem and the wall outlet (switch, splitter, patch panel, magic)? Does the computer plugged to the wall report a negotiated link speed higher than 100?

Comment: There were no other devices in between, but i took the advice of rewiring properly and that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cable looks machine-made, so that would be the least likely suspect, especially as the socket wiring looks a disaster (sorry, but true;)

You could get a cable tester & check it out, but it looks like the socket wiring just wasn't punched down properly.
So you could save your money on a cable tester & just buy a proper punch-down tool instead. [metal with spring-loaded punch & cut mechanism, about $£€ 20] Plastic punch-down tools aren't worth the money & trying to punch-down with a screwdriver etc will just damage the socket without stripping the wire properly.
Proper tool for a proper job. Anything else is false economy.

Comment: Thanks, took your advise, bought a network tool kit and rewired properly. I also bought a new wall socket to be sure. Hooked it all up and now im getting optimal speed again!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to rewire?

Sometimes it looks wired correctly but it still gives issues (had it before with an 1gbit cable defaulting to 100mbit and after a rewire it was fixed)

Comment: No good just rewiring it with the same "press it in with your thumbnail" technique used the last time ;))

Answer (score 0):

> When i run a speedtest on my computer by directly connecting to the
> wall socket, i get around 90 Mbit/s. However, if i run a cable
> directly from my modem to my computer, i get 270 Mbit/s.   .....
> don't think its even possible to replace the cable since it doesnt
> budge when i pull it on either side.

It is possibly an issue with the cable itself.

You need to get a network technician to assess the situation and:

(a) remake cable connections that test bad with the technician's test equipment. Some of the connections look suspect.

(b) test the cable and suggest how to replace the cable.

I assume you do not own cable test gear, so it is better to purchase this skill in the form of a technician.